# IIS Server Anonymous Authentication Changed

Tags: sharepoint-2013, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I have a SharePoint 2013 server for development purposes, that runs on Win 2012. The problem is that after a period of time the anonymous authentication changes by itself.

In IIS, select the server name, than from the right panel under IIS double click Authentication. From the page that opens right click Anonymous Authentication and select Edit from the context menu.

Than will pop-up a credentials selector window.

The correct value should be first option: Specific user (IUSR account) but the option select is the second one: Application pool identity.

If I change it back to Specific user and select IUSR, after a while is back to Application pool identity.

Any ideas how can I investigate what app/software is messing up with my settings?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the IIS event logs or security logs?